# How to use session in shrio?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, authority

I am a Chinese student, and recently I used springMVC+shrio, but in the program I can't use session, as every time I need authority, it will do the following method: `doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)`, then find database and search authority and so on.

```
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(
            PrincipalCollection principals) {
        /* 这里编写授权代码 */
        Object ob = principals.fromRealm(getName()).iterator().next(); 
        String userName = (String) ob; 
        User user = roleService.findUser(userName);
        Set<String> roleNames = roleService.findRoleName(user.getId());
        Set<String> permissions = roleService.findUrls(user.getId());
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
        info.setStringPermissions(permissions);
        return info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i find a answer,just because i haven't use cache.

add some config:

```
<!-- 配置EHCache缓存 -->
 <property name="cacheManager" ref="shiroEhcacheManager" />
```

-->